# Unexpected result with System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For with Openxml

Tags: c#, multithreading, openxml

I am using the following code

```
SheetData sheetdata = worksheet.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For((excelStartRow + 1), (endRowvalue + 1),
  (i) =>
  {
      Row contentRow = new Row();

      //do something

      Cell content = createTextCell(
          dtspSheetData.Tables[0].Columns.IndexOf(column) + excelStartColumn, i,
          dtspSheetData.Tables[0].Rows[j][column.ColumnName],
          formatCount, 1, cellFormatCount);
      contentRow.AppendChild(content);

      sheetData.AppendChild(contentRow);
  });
```

I am tryin to implement parallelelism while creating an Excel using OpenXML.Problem is that Rows are created in the Excel file but some rows are not getting created and shows a warning while opening the while.I understand that sheetData object is locked when other threads are tring to insert the row to the sheetData object. How can i rectify this problem.

Comment: Does it work without using Parallel.For?

Comment: Yeah.It is working without Parallel For.

Comment: You should check  if all methods are thread-safe. For example, the createTextCell method, is it thread-safe?

Comment: The createTextCell method doesnt do any write operation.Only a cell object is created.Problem is the entire row fails to get appended to the sheet.

Answer (score 3):

These Excel objects are not designed to be accessed from multiple threads simultaneously.  Given that the only particularly "expensive" task you are performing within this loop is one that must be serialized, your best bet would be to simply do the whole thing in one thread, in a regular `for` loop.

If actually computing the value of each cell was expensive then you could *potentially* consider a parallel loop to simply generate the contents of each cell, putting them into some intermediate storage location in memory, and then copy those values to Excel from a single thread, but as this loop doesn't appear to be doing any such expensive computation, there is no need to do that here.

Comment: Thank you Servy.The intermediate Storage location is getting locked when threads are trying to access it, as a result only few rows are added

Comment: The problem is not accessing the data from whereever your reading it from, the problem is that you're trying to write that data to an excel file from multiple threads, and it doesn't support that.  You need to write the data out to excel sequentially.  The only thing that could be meaningfully parallelized (depending on what you're doing) is populating the data source you're pulling data from here.